# replace's function access the ecapsulating object?

Tags: javascript, function, replace

I am creating an attribute in a javascript object by replacing some strings in an existing object, as a side effect I want to make some additional changes to a third property, which I try to access with this.property however in the replace function this is referring to the window instead of my 'master' object. How can I pass in the encapsulating object, so that I can use `this` to access third property.

```
b = {
    a: 'onetwothree',
    count: 0,
    rp: function () {
        this.c = this.a.replace(/e/g, function (str, evalstr) {
            this.count++; // <-- this is refering to window.
            return 'e' + this.count
        })
    }
};
b.rp();
```

`b.c = 'oneNaNtwothreNaNeNaN` whereas I want it to be `one1twothre2e3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rp: function () {
    this.c = this.a.replace(/e/g, function (str, evalstr) {
        this.count++;
        return 'e' + this.count
    }.bind( this )) // <-- bind the function
}
```

Comment: thank you 'this', but I still do prefer the operator first syntax (, key: val opposed to key: val, )

Comment: @drjerry sure but your original code was completely unreadable for everyone else, so I just ran it through a beautifier tool which puts commas after.

Comment: Be aware that `bind()` is a relative new function not available in all browsers (safari mobile choked on it), you may want to refere to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can usually solve this by making use of the closure you're creating, like this:

```
b = {
    a: 'onetwothree',
    count: 0,
    rp: function () {
        var self = this;             // <-- Create a variable to point to this
        this.c = this.a.replace(/e/g, function (str, evalstr) {
            self.count++;            // <-- And use it here
            return 'e' + self.count; // <-- And here (also added the ;)
        })
    }
};
b.rp();
```

More to explore *(disclosure: both are posts on my blog)*:

- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Answer (score 2):

Cache the `this` context in another variable.

```
rp: function () {
     var self = this; // Cache here
     this.c = this.a.replace(/e/g, function(str, evalstr) {
         return 'e' + (++self.count); // Use here
     });
}
```

Protip: ++self.count gives the new value *after* incrementing.